# My ally demesne levy size bigger than maximum, how he achieved it?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Currently I am playing as Serbian king, and I am allied with Bulgarian Tsar.

Looking at his character: 
[image]

I noticed his demesne levy size are way above maximum. How he achieved it?

NOTE: No mods or dlc activated

Comment: I have some ideas, not worth a full reply: he might've raised an army an then got some negative modifiers - got injured or sick, that lowers martial skill. Or his holdings got pillaged or struck by disease. You don't lose raised troops even when the max becomes lower

Answer (score 1):

A possible explanation could be that Petar's levy capacity got reduced for some reason while he already had all his troops risen.

Possible causes for losing levy troop capacity could be that he lost a couple titles from his demesne (to other realms or to his vassals) or lost a couple points in martial skill (maybe he just recently lost a trait or temporary effect which gave him a bonus to martial?).

Answer (score 1):

Few possible explanations.

1. He has raised levies, but then lost something (titles, martial
   points, etc.) that have brought max down without losing troops
   directly.
2. He has mercenaries or personal guard currently active,
   that are bringing his total troop count above max levies.

Comment: Regarding 2: Wouldn't those show up as separate list items?

Comment: Only in greater breakdown. On dropdown lists like Bojan shows, they (for some reason only known to Paradox) they show up as levies.